# Undo git mv (rename)

Tags: git, rename, undo, mv

What is the right way to undo a rename in git, like:

```
git mv file1 file2
```

Comment: Cheeky answer: `git mv file2 file1`

Comment: @CanSpice: That is the correct answer; nothing cheeky about it.

Comment: @Charles: Well then, I've supplied it as a proper non-cheeky answer. :-)

Comment: git mv file2 file1 You expected anything else?

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Non-cheeky answer:

```
git mv file2 file1
```

> Updates the index for both old and new paths automatically.

Check documentation of [git mv](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv)

Comment: suppose file1 and file2 are both in current directory (.), then why `git checkout .` doesn't work, even with the `-f` option?

Comment: It seems rare that things are as intuitive as this :)

Comment: @ryenus You need to use `git checkout -- .`.

Comment: Lol. That's fun.

Comment: Did not work for me giving the error: `fatal: source directory is empty,`, only `git reset --hard` did the job.

Answer (score 51):

If you have done no other changes (that you want to keep) since the last commit, you can do

```
git reset --hard
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to get in the habit of using `git reset --hard`. Just moving it backwards seems a safer option to me.

Comment: Worked for me.  I wanted to undo a "git mv" that 1) had not yet been committed, and 2) I had no other chages

Comment: If you have other changes you want to keep, this will destroy all of them.

Answer (score 16):

```
git reset HEAD file2
```

did the trick for me

Comment: The only issue I had with this answer is that it left copies for file2 on disk.

Comment: Also leaves `file1` staged for deletion.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I moved an entire folder, then realized I should not have.

I really liked @Dave Konopka's answer, but I did not have much success with that approach (maybe my version of GIT (1.8.4)?  My files still showed as deleted.  I had other changes on the stack that I did not want to lose (unfortunately).

I did have success doing this:

```
git reset moved_folder
git checkout original_folder
```

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what you want to accomplish.  If you want it to appear as if the file was never moved, then you can reset (or rebase) back to before the move.  If you don't care about the history, then just move it back.

Comment: First one works fine as long as you haven't pushed your commit, or someone hasn't pulled from you.

Answer (score 7):

If you've accidentally renamed a large number of files and want to get back to where you started, delete all the renamed files that show up as `adds` under a `git status` call.

Once you delete all the changed files you can run `git checkout -- *` to get back the original file names locally.

Answer (score 6):

```
git reset HEAD file2
git checkout -- file1
rm file2
```

The first command unstages file2 but leaves a copy of it around. The second command restores the original file and the third deletes the new file.

Answer (score 3):

The trick I used was to do a git stash to undo all my changes (which includes restoring the mv'd files) and then deleted the stash with git stash drop.

Answer (score 0):

Less scary is to go to top level of the repo and do:

git reset
git checkout .

Comment: caution: this cancels all the changes, not only the 'git mv'

Answer (score 0):

I liked @Kamaraju Kusumanchi's answer. However, I could not properly checkout file1 because it was staged for deletion at that point. So a better answer may be

```
git reset HEAD file2 file1
git checkout -- file1
rm file2
```

I actually did the reset in two steps since I was following Kamaraju's suggestion. So the reset might need to be done in two steps. Simply said, resetting just file2 leaves file1 staged for deletion. So both the rename and the deletion need to be unstaged before reverting file1 with a checkout.